# Where is io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Bismuth-RC1?

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

Although Spring Reactor Core 3.1.0.RC1 et.al. is available I cannot find io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Bismuth-RC1. I'd like to test it with the latest Spring WebFlux. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactor Core 3.1.0.RC1 has been released only a few hours ago.
The Reactor BOM manages versions for many Reactor projects, including Reactor Netty which is not yet released.

You should get an official announcement on https://spring.io/blog and [@ProjectReactor](https://twitter.com/ProjectReactor).